# Why do LR and Wald p-values differ by orders of magnitude?

Tags: p-value, likelihood-ratio

My application is a Cox model with n=685 and one continuous predictor

```
mod <- coxph(srv ~ predi)
```

`summary(mod)` gives a p-value for the coefficient of about $10^{-6}$

`anova(mod)` gives a p-value of $>10^{-4}$

I can reproduce these p-values using the `Anova` function in the `car` package:

```
library(car)
Anova(mod, test.statistic="Wald")
Anova(mod, test.statistic="LR")
```

What are possible explanations for this discrepancy? Should I prefer the LR p-value?
Neither `predi` nor the bootstrapped distribution of its Hazard Ratio look normally distributed. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but I do know that estimating very small p is tricky. This is yet another reason to emphasize effect size rather than p value.